# Windows 10 file history backup fails at starting with error 80070005 - why?

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup, file-history

Since February 2021 the Windows file history backup hasn't been backing up anymore. Trying to restart it manually (using the corresponding control panel) would lead to the error "Failed to initiate user data backup (error 80070005)". What causes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused by a faulty Windows 10 update and was resolved with the April [KB5001330](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/5001330) update.

Source: [File History Does Not Work](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-history-does-not-work/a0b89be2-fbac-4c99-ad5b-0e40b227cd5f) (from answers.microsoft.com)